# How can i change meta (alt and title) in catalog thumbnail , product thumbnail ? - Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, meta

By default in `Woocommerce` for alt  used image file's name.

Does anyone  know  how to change thumbnail meta (alt and title)  to show *Product name*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){
    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Get post type to check if it's product
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    /// Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've updated XciD's answer to a much cleaner version:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);
function change_attachement_image_attributes($attr, $attachment) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $attr['alt'] = $title;
        $attr['title'] = $title;
    }
    return $attr;
}
```

Unfortunately on the main image the script doesn't work for me (XciD's neither), but on the small thumbs it is. Interesting :)

Update: If I turn off the main image, then the script starts working from the second thumb!

Update 2: Ok. It was an "Oh God Please No!" situation as some *bad words* JS code changed the alt tag. OMG...