# How to automatically use image meta title of featured image as product name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to use the title of the image meta description to get used as a new title in the product name in woocommerce.

So when you upload a featured product image name: featuredimage123.jpg the product name changes to "featuredimage123".

I found the other way around that the image meta updates with the product title here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258007/how-to-automatically-apply-woocommerce-product-title-to-all-product-images-alt-t

Is it possible to get this done the other way?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I looked at the hooks for woocommerce and found out how to get the image attributes via wp_get_attachement_image_attributes, but then I dont know how to get the title from the image transferred over to product-title. I think the code which I linked shoud have all the answers but I am such a beginner. Here the Code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087772/how-can-i-change-meta-alt-and-title-in-catalog-thumbnail-product-thumbnail#27087948