# Woocommerce product image alt text - set automatically

Tags: woocommerce

I wasn't able to respond to the [original posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087772/how-can-i-change-meta-alt-and-title-in-catalog-thumbnail-product-thumbnail) as it was closed.

The code snippet provided in the link works; however it changes my logo alt text in the header to the alt text of the first product image.

Can anyone advise how can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This will add in the product title to the alt tag on the shop page.

```
function modify_shop_product_image ( $img, $product, $size, $attr, $placeholder ) {
    $alt_tag = 'alt=';
    $pos = stripos( $img, 'alt=' ) + strlen( $alt_tag ) + 1;
    return substr_replace($img, $product->get_name(), $pos, 0);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'modify_shop_product_image', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - it does correct the header logo alt text but from what I can see that puts the image title as the alt text - it doesnt put the product title as the alt text

Comment: It should have any affect on the header logo it's a WooCommerce action, I checked it with my theme and all the products on the shop page have an alt tag image with the product name.  Screenshot attached showing the alt tag in the image. 
http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2032/WA07Fs.png

Comment: I am not sure how to upload a photo here. That code does not react the same way on my store (local) It takes the alt text from the media library, not the alt text of the product title. Perhaps I have an override with code snippets somewhere...  Would you mind quickly checking your media library and see what the alt text is listed at for that product in your media library ?

Comment: I'm using the product title for the alt text, nothing to do with the image meta data at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct code snippet

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){
    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Get post type to check if it's product
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    if ( isset( $attr['class'] ) && 'custom-logo' === $attr['class'] ) {
        return $attr;
    }

    /// Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**add to function.php**

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes($attr, $attachment) {
global $post;
if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;
}
return $attr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to set the ALT tags of your logo in the Media, then use the script to check if the ALT tag is empty and **only** replace it if it is. This can be also applied to other images that you don't want the Alt tags to be overridden.  Another thing that was giving me issues was product titles that had quotes as the alt tag is enclosed by quotes, in my case I replaced them with the word in. for inches, just something to be aware if you have quotes in the titles, you have to replace them based on your application.

```
//This will add in the product title to the alt tag on the shop page.
function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){
    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);
    // Get post type to check if it's product
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }
    
    if($attr['alt']=='') {
        // Get title and remove any double quotes
        $title = str_replace('"',' in.', get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent));
        $attr['alt'] = $title;
        $attr['title'] = $title;
    }
    return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);
```